# How do I find the element by coordinate in VTK?

Tags: python, c++, vtk, gmsh

I have a mesh file generate by Gmsh(*.vtu), the mesh is a cube area and consist of tetrahedrons. Then I have a point (given by coordinate) in the cube, I want to find which tetrahedron contains the point, how did I do?

```
with pygmsh.occ.Geometry() as geom:
    geom.add_box([0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1], mesh_size=0.1)
    mesh = geom.generate_mesh()
mesh.write('original_gmsh.vtu')

uGridReader = vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
uGridReader.SetFileName('original_gmsh.vtu')
uGridReader.Update()
uGrid: vtkUnstructuredGrid = uGridReader.GetOutput()

givenPoint = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [FindAndGetCell()](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSet.html#a2237e772166dbbfb6421ee2e8f4492d1) method that vtkUnstructuredGrid inherits from vtkDataSet. The python documentation for this can be found using `help(vtkUnstructuredGrid.FindAndGetCell)` within your python shell (assuming you have imported vtkUnstructuredGrid, if not prepend with vtk. as usual.

As a recommendation, consider check out the PyVista package, its far easier to use in my experience and uses VTK as its backend as well.